# How to fix java intermittent lags?

Tags: java, performance, lag, frame-rate

The same code in my project has different execution duration for the same input parameters, it varies from 1ms to 30ms.

```
private void link(Array values, Area area){
   values.add(area);
   Array<Area> children = area.getChildren();
   for (int i=0; i<children.size; i++){
       Area child = children.get(i);
       link(values, child);
   }
}
```

This lags are inappropriate. Can I fix them?

Comment: does the execution depend on the size of the input? could it be caused by garbage collection? could it be measuring imprecisions?

Comment: GC is reasonable, I have to check it, thanks. The input is the same, the measurement is good enough

Comment: Is `Array` really an array? If not, you shouldn't direct-access it, you should iterate it: `for (Area child : area.getChildren()) { link(values, child); }` if it's `Iterable,` otherwise use an `Iterator` yourself.

Comment: Iterating did not help much. Thanks for reply!

Comment: What does `link()` actually do? It looks like most of the time could be spent inside it rather than here.

Comment: You are right. It is because GC. That's why lags happen intermittently

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Intermittent lags are caused by garbage collection.